# Unable to pass beans from testContext to applicationContext using spring and junit

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, junit, spring-test

I have a test automation library that I can get to work with dagger and guice, but I'm trying to change the project over to using spring-test (per a client's request).

Here's what the test runner originally looked like, with the simpler DI approach..

**JUnit Runner (Pre-Spring)**

```
public class AutomationJUnit4Runner extends ParentRunner<Runner>
{
  private final Runner runner;

  public AutomationJUnit4Runner(Class<?> testClass) throws InitializationError
  {
    super(testClass);

    boolean proxied = testClass.isAnnotationPresent(EnableProxiedWebDriver.class);
    this.runner = browserRunners(testClass, ConfigHolder.CAPABILITIES, proxied);
  }

  private Runner browserRunners(final Class<?> klass, Iterable<DesiredCapabilities> capabilities, boolean proxiedWebDriver)
          throws InitializationError
  {
    final List<Runner> runners = Lists.newArrayList();

    for(DesiredCapabilities c : capabilities)
    {
      runners.add(new BrowserRunner(klass, c, proxiedWebDriver));
    }

    return new Suite(klass, runners){ };
  }

   private static class BrowserRunner extends BlockJUnit4ClassRunner
   {
      private final DesiredCapabilities capabilities;
      private boolean isProxiedWebDriver;

      BrowserRunner(Class<?> testClass, Capabilities capabilities, boolean proxiedWebDriver) throws InitializationError
      {
        super(testClass);
        this.capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities(capabilities);
        this.isProxiedWebDriver = proxiedWebDriver;
      }   

      @Override
      protected Object createTest() throws Exception
      {
        Object test = super.createTest();

        if(test instanceof RequiresInjection)
        {
          WebDriverModule module = new WebDriverModule(capabilities, isProxiedWebDriver);
          ObjectGraph objectGraph = ObjectGraph.create(concat(getModules((RequiresInjection) test), module));

          objectGraph.inject(test);
        }
        return test;
      }
```

I tried switching the tests over to using the Spring junit runner, but I ran into an exception regarding the capabilities:

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'WebDriverModule': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

It makes sense, as the capabilities are loaded at runtime (it's done to support running the suite against multiple browsers), so I figured I would see if there was a way to get those capabilities injected into the context.

The TestExecutionListeners in the Spring documentation looked promising, so I gave it a try..

**JUnit Runner - Spring**

```
  private static class BrowserRunner extends SpringJUnit4ClassRunner
  {
    // .. skipping over misc.

    @Override
    protected Object createTest() throws Exception
    {
        TestContextManager testContextManager = getTestContextManager();
        testContextManager.registerTestExecutionListeners(new WebDriverTestExecutionListener(capabilities, isProxiedWebDriver));

        return super.createTest();
    }
```

**WebDriverTestExecutionListener**

```
@Override
public void beforeTestClass(TestContext testContext) throws Exception {

    ApplicationContext tc = testContext.getApplicationContext();
    if (tc instanceof ConfigurableApplicationContext)
    {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext configurableTestContext = (ConfigurableApplicationContext) tc;
        ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory = configurableTestContext.getBeanFactory();
        beanFactory.registerResolvableDependency(Capabilities.class, capabilities);
        // todo: figure out isProxied after 'caps' is working
        configurableTestContext.refresh();
    }

}
```

However, I'm still running into the same issue. The "beforeTestClass" isn't called in time to satisfy the dependencies of the page objects.

Is there another way to make these capabilities available to the tests and page objects the moment I instantiate them?